# angularjs ui-router: How to make a transition from state "parent" to "parent.firstchild"?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

Parent state:

```
var roundsState = {
  name : 'rounds', 
  url: '/rounds',
  component: 'rounds',
  resolve : {
    rounds : function(RoundsService){
      return RoundsService.getRounds();
    }
  }
};
```

Child state:

```
var roundState = {
  name : 'rounds.round', 
  url: '/{roundUri}',
  component: 'round',
  resolve: {
    round: function(RoundsService, $transition$, $stateParams) {
      return RoundsService.getRound($transition$.params().roundUri);
    }
  }
};
```

Trying to use:

```
app.run(function($transitions) {
  $transitions.onSuccess({ to: 'rounds' }, function(trans) {
    return trans.router.stateService.go('rounds.round');
  });   
});
```

When a transition to state "rounds" is successful, I want to go for state "rounds.round" but to the first child. I was reading about grandchild but I didn't understand it.

Note that I'm using ui-router 1.x

Here is the implemented example on plnkr: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/0C4aSB3a3fllYxa022Aq?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `roundUri` parameter for `rounds.round` state. You could have known that had you seen the console! :)

So, I changed it to something like this:

```
trans.router.stateService.go('rounds.round', {roundUri: "firstround"});
```

And it works!

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MMkD2amwimtSHM89VR7v?p=preview)

**EDIT**:

**How to go to a child state dynamically?** (*in `ui-router` v1.0*)

Well, you can decide that inside `$transitions.onSuccess`. You can inject certain dependencies and decide where to go. Like this:

```
app.run(function($transitions, RoundsService) {
  $transitions.onSuccess({ to: 'rounds' }, function(trans) {
    RoundsService.getRounds().then(function(rounds) {
        return trans.router.stateService.go('rounds.round', {roundUri: rounds[0].uri});
    })
  });
});
```

Notice how I determine which child URI to visit using the service call `RoundsService.getRounds()`.

I have modified the `rounds.json` so that some other state (say `roundof16`) is first now. And, it goes to that state! :)

[**Updated plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MMkD2amwimtSHM89VR7v?p=preview) for Dynamic child state visit.

Answer (score 0):

Well I use this with $state and there it's fairly straightforward:

```
$state.go('rounds.round', {});
```

I don't think you should really be using $transition$ as you don't really need to.

Comment: In ui-router 1.x as per migration page, $transition$ must be used: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events. Anyway, **$state.go('rounds.round', {});** is similar to **trans.router.stateService.go('rounds.round', {});** but what I want is to make a transition to the first child in rounds.round

Answer (score 0):

You can write state.js like:

```
angular.module('sampleApp')
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
            var $state = $injector.get('$state');
            $state.go('home');
        });

        $stateProvider

            .state('parent', {
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'views/parent/index.html'
            })

            .state('child', {
                parent: 'parent',
                abstract: true,
                url: '/child',
                template: '<ui-view/>'
            })

            .state('child.add', {
                url: '/add',
                templateUrl: 'views/child/add.html'
            });
}]);
```

and then access in HTML like:

```
<a href="#" ui-sref="child.add"><span>Add Child</span></a>
```